# AMDGPU Excessive Logging

Tags: amdgpu

I have just noticed that AMDGPU is logging excessively into syslog. `tail -f /var/log/syslog` shows hundreds of messages being logged every second. Is there any way I can stop this from happening as it is obviously clogging up other items. Example output:

```
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.264629] [drm:amdgpu_dm_do_flip [amdgpu]] amdgpu_dm_do_flip Flipping to hi: 0xf5, low: 0xe3fa0000
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.264713] [drm:amdgpu_dm_do_flip [amdgpu]] amdgpu_dm_do_flip Flipping to hi: 0xf5, low: 0xe3fa0000
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.268910] [drm:dm_pflip_high_irq [amdgpu]] dm_pflip_high_irq - crtc :0[00000000beca4895], pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_NONE
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.269012] [drm:dm_pflip_high_irq [amdgpu]] dm_pflip_high_irq - crtc :1[00000000a5d17dd9], pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_NONE
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.277957] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] amdgpu_crtc id:0 crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.278032] [drm:handle_cursor_update.isra.23 [amdgpu]] handle_cursor_update: crtc_id=0 with size 128 to 128
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.280801] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] amdgpu_crtc id:0 crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.280881] [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] amdgpu_crtc id:1 crtc_state_flags: enable:1, active:1, planes_changed:1, mode_changed:0,active_changed:0,connectors_changed:0
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.280970] [drm:prepare_flip_isr [amdgpu]] crtc:1, pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_SUBMITTED
Jun 12 08:50:49 tim-home kernel: [  367.281040] [drm:prepare_flip_isr [amdgpu]] crtc:0, pflip_stat:AMDGPU_FLIP_SUBMITTED
```